# Using VBA in excel to provide a warning on start up if a value in a column falls below an integer

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel document with multiple worksheets. One of the worksheets is titled "Inventory". It tracks how much of each product we have and when these products expire. In one of the columns, it lists the "Days until expiration" for each material we have. I want to write a VBA script so that every time I open my excel file, the script runs and checks all the values in the "Days until expiration column". If there is a value in the column that is within 14 days of expiration, I want the script to pop-up upon the excel file starting up and say something like "____ material has # days left before expiration". Please advise.

Comment: Your question isn't specific enough, there are many different ways to do this. What have you tried? Please see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Please see the new revised question

Comment: Check out the [`Workbook_Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196215.aspx) event

Comment: Bruce is correct. Under Microsoft Excel Objects (in vba) on "ThisWorkbook" there is a Worbook (object) Open (action) that will run code when the workbook opens. Put your vba code there.

Comment: that said, your list of values could just as well use a conditional formatting formula that compares with today's date and formats problematic values in bold red with a bright yellow background - no VBA involved =)

Comment: I currently have a conditional formatting formula that does exactly that but my boss would like a pop up upon opening the excel workbook lol... If I use the Workbook_open function, what would the vba code that I use be? The "Days until expiration" is in column i of the "Inventory" sheet. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the expiration dates are on column D, then please consider the following code to be added to your `Workbook_Open` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngUsed As Range, rngExpirationColumn As Range, rngCell As Range
    Dim strExpirationMessage As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Inventory")
    Set rngUsed = ws.UsedRange
    Set rngExpirationColumn = Intersect(ws.Columns(4), rngUsed)

    For Each rngCell In rngExpirationColumn.Cells
        If Date - CDate(rngCell.Value2) >= 14 Then
            If Len(strExpirationMessage) = 0 Then
                strExpirationMessage = rngCell.Offset(0, -3).Value2 & " material has " & (Date - CDate(rngCell.Value2)) & " days left before expiration"
            Else
                strExpirationMessage = strExpirationMessage & Chr(13) & rngCell.Offset(0, -3).Value2 & " material has " & (Date - CDate(rngCell.Value2)) & " days left before expiration"
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox strExpirationMessage
End Sub
```